# JavaScript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've got a function that takes 3 parameters. The problem I have is one of the parameters is a property of a sometimes undefined value of an Object (i.e. it takes in **thing.foo.bar**, and sometimes **thing.foo** is undefined, so it can't access *bar*).

What's a way around this? Within the function's declaration, I have a conditional checking:
 `if (!parameterName)`, but the browser (Chrome) is still throwing an error that it can't read the **bar** property of undefined.

Comment: might consider "optional chaining" ex: `thing?.foo?.bar`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If an object's property may refer to some other object then you can test *that* for undefined before trying to use its properties:

```
if (thing && thing.foo)
   alert(thing.foo.bar);
```

I could update my answer to better reflect your situation if you show some actual code, but possibly something like this:

```
function someFunc(parameterName) {
   if (parameterName && parameterName.foo)
       alert(parameterName.foo.bar);
}
```

Comment: @Mörre: This works just fine. OP explicitly states that `thing.foo` is undefined, so it _has_ to be declared.

Answer (score 11):

Compound checking:

```
   if (thing.foo && thing.foo.bar) {
      ... thing.foor.bar exists;
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can safeguard yourself either of these two ways:

```
function myFunc(thing) {
    if (thing && thing.foo && thing.foo.bar) {
        // safe to use thing.foo.bar here
    }
}

function myFunc(thing) {
    try {
        var x = thing.foo.bar;
        // do something with x
    } catch(e) {
        // do whatever you want when thing.foo.bar didn't work
    }
}
```

In the first example, you explicitly check all the possible elements of the variable you're referencing to make sure it's safe before using it so you don't get any unplanned reference exceptions.

In the second example, you just put an exception handler around it.  You just access `thing.foo.bar` assuming it exists.  If it does exist, then the code runs normally.  If it doesn't exist, then it will throw an exception which you will catch and ignore.  The end result is the same.  If `thing.foo.bar` exists, your code using it executes.  If it doesn't exist that code does not execute.  In all cases, the function runs normally.

The `if` statement is faster to execute.  The exception can be simpler to code and use in complex cases where there may be many possible things to protect against and your code is structured so that throwing an exception and handling it is a clean way to skip execution when some piece of data does not exist.  Exceptions are a bit slower when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 8):

Just check for it before you pass to your function. So you would pass:

```
thing.foo ? thing.foo.bar : undefined
```