# Having problems when using objects passed through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I have a public 'bullets' array that I'm pushing a private bullet object into. It has x and y properties and I want to change it's y property so that every time I press the space key it creates a bullet object, pushes it into the bullets array and then calls a function that loops through the array and updates each bullet's y property.

However, every time I press the space key I get an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined

This is slightly beyond my understanding and I'm not sure how I can write this so that the bullet objects in the bullets array are not 'undefined'.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate the help.

```
   //called every frame
    function playGame()
    {
        movePlayer();
        playerShoot();
        moveBullet();
    }

    //PLAYER SHOOT FUNCTION
    //If the space key is down, player.shoot is true and the bullet object is created.

    function playerShoot()
    {
        if(player.shoot)
        {
            var bullet = Object.create(spriteObject);
            bullet.width = 16;
            bullet.height = 16;
            bullet.x = (player.width - bullet.width) / 2;
            bullet.y = (player.height - bullet.height) / 2;
            bullets.push(bullet);
            player.shoot = false;
        }
    }

    //MOVING THE BULLET
    function moveBullet()
    {
        if(bullets.length !== 0)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i <= bullets.length; i++)
            {
                var bullet = bullets[i];
                console.log("bullet: " + bullet);

                //bullet.y causes error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined

                if((bullet.y + bullet.height) >= 0)
                {
                    bullet.y--;
                }
                else
                {
                    bullets.splice[i, 0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //RENDERING THE BULLETS
    function renderBullet()
    {
        if(bullets.length !== 0)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i <= bullets.length; i++)
            {
                var bullet = bullets[i];
                bullet.render();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= bullets.length; i++)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
```

In your code, the last iteration gets `bullets[bullets.length]`, which is `undefined`. So comes the error.

This error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined

Indicates that the object is `undefined`, so cannot access the property `y` on it. So always make sure your object is defined before accessing properties on it.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! That has solved the problem.

Comment: @CerpinTaxt My pleasure. You may upvote or accept the answer :). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use < instead of <= less than or equal to will iterate one time more than the bullets array resulting in your loop iterating over a non existing element. In addition to not using <= and using < you can also check if bullet exists and only execute your if or else blocks if condition is met.

```
  if((bullet && bullet.y + bullet.height) >= 0) {
      bullet.y--;
  } else {
      bullets.splice(i, 0);
  }
```

Comment: `bullets.splice[i, 0];`  -> `bullets.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: @aduch whoops, just copying what the OP posted didn't realize that was wrong :)