# Cannot read property 'temperature' of undefined in nodejs, I am using ATOM editor for this

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

```
const request = require('request');

var darkKey = (val1, val2) => {

return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

request({   
url:`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4dbb4a208092a27372b0e574065729f2/${val1},${val2}`,

    JSON:true
  },(error,response,body) => {
    if(error){
        reject('not connected to server');
    } else if(response.statusCode === 400){
        reject('problem with lat and long');
    } else if(response.statusCode === 200){
        resolve(body.currently.temperature);
    }
  });
  });
};

darkKey(18.5770, 73.6872).then((res) => {

console.log(res);

},(error) => {

  console.log(error);

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined)

Comment: Should be `json: true`, not `JSON: true`.