# Timer with React cannot read property seconds of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a timer in React but, I have a problem. 
The error that I am getting is this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined'.`

I have tried to understand but, I can't find the problem.

Can someone help me ?

Here is the fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/17/

Thank you.

I think the problem is here because if I comment the render, it's ok.

````
<TimerInput 
    value={this.state.seconds} 
    handleChange={this.handleChange} 
/> 
<Minuteur 
    seconds={600} 
    libelle="Pâtes"
/>```
````

Comment: That error means you are trying to read the `seconds` field of something before it has been defined. There's nothing there yet. 

This problem arises [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined).

(BTW, this is a problem that cannot arise in some static typed languages, such as Haskell, because they make it impossible to create a thing that has no value.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Levi's answer (as I'm not allowed to comment yet):

Your TimerInput component is trying to read prop seconds (not value), so your render line for it should look like:

```
<TimerInput seconds={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access the state and methods of the `Minuteur` component from the parent component `App`.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
    <div>
      <TimerInput value={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      <Minuteur seconds={600} libelle="Pâtes"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`this.state.seconds` and `this.handleChange` refer to attributes on the `Minuteur` component. Since it seems like `TimerInput` and `Minuteur` need to share some state, you have a couple options.

1. Combine the `TimerInput` and `Minuteur` components into one so they have the same state.
2. Create a wrapping component that contains both `TimerInput` and `Minuteur` and move the shared state (e.g. `state.seconds`) to that component.

The approach for option 2 would look roughly like this:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      seconds: 0
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      seconds: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TimerInput value={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Minuteur seconds={this.state.seconds} libelle="Pâtes"/>
      </div>
    )
  }


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this error now... react-dom.development.js:49 Uncaught Error: Wrapper(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/26/

Comment: I can't see your error, but see MrAleister's answer for another correction you need to make. I just updated my answer with it.

Comment: I missed a return statement in `render()`. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add return to the Wrapper's render:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <TimerInput seconds={this.state.seconds} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      <Minuteur seconds={this.state.seconds} libelle="Pâtes"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution - set initial Wrapper seconds state to anything but 0 (like 600 you had in your original fiddle):

```
this.state = { 
  seconds: 600
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want the input change in real time the seconds ;)

Comment: Ok - issue is with your TimerInput component lacking the state. Here is an answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input

Comment: I need to add a constructor on TimerInput ??