# Cannot read property 'Drivers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api

Its my first time posting here but i'm desperate for a solution. I'm sorry in advance if my question format is not proper. So basically what i'm struggling with is appending json data to paragraphs in my html. My API is okay, i checked with console.log the data is there, but every time i try to append the data, an error pops up in my console stating: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Drivers' of undefined.

I've tried removing MRData from function but that didn't seem to do anything.

```
     $.getJSON("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/drivers.json", function(MRData) {
        console.log(MRData);
        var drId = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId;
        var permanentNum = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].permanentNumber;
        var kod = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].code;
        $('#p0').append(drId);
        $('#p1').append(permanentNum);
        $('#p2').append(kod);
   })
    <body>
          <p id="p0"></p>
          <p id="p1"></p>
          <p id="p2"></p>
    </body>
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish here is to get the strings from each of the variables and to append them to my paragraphs.

Comment: post your `console.log` output too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined)

Comment: `MRData.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId` etc. Your parsed JSON is an object with a key called `MRData`. Call your callback argument `data` and then do `data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId` and it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Yup that solved it, i renamed my callback argument into data and everything is okay now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you think that the result data is `MRData` but instead it is an object which holds `MRData`.

```
data = {
    MRData: {...}
}
```

accessing to MRData will make your code to work.

```js
$.getJSON("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/drivers.json", function(data) {
  //data is an object which will have MRData inside.
  var MRData = data.MRData;
  var drId = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId;
  var permanentNum = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].permanentNumber;
  var kod = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].code;
  $('#p0').append(drId);
  $('#p1').append(permanentNum);
  $('#p2').append(kod);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p id="p0"></p>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
var MRData =data.MRData;
        console.log(data.MRData);
        var drId = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId;
        var permanentNum = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].permanentNumber;
        var kod = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].code;
        $('#p0').append(drId);
        $('#p1').append(permanentNum);
        $('#p2').append(kod);
   })
```

your reciver data has field `MRData` and you use `var MRData =data.MRData;`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the json file you have a variable mrData so your start should be

```
MRData.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers
```

if you have a look at your json file it says

```
{ 
  MRData={}
}
```

adding `MRData= MRData.MRData;` should fix the problem. or you could simple modify the jsonfile content to `{DriverTable:{// bla bla bla }}`

```js
    $.getJSON("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/drivers.json", function(MRData) {
        console.log(MRData);
        MRData= MRData.MRData; // here is a simple workout
      
        var drId = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].driverId;
        var permanentNum = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].permanentNumber;
        var kod = MRData.DriverTable.Drivers[0].code;
        $('#p0').append(drId);
        $('#p1').append(permanentNum);
        $('#p2').append(kod);
        
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
          <p id="p0"></p>
          <p id="p1"></p>
          <p id="p2"></p>
    </body>
```