# Detecting an undefined/null object property in an aplication vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

Detecting an undefined/null object property in an aplication vue.

I can not resolve this object problem not defined.

I am using a vue application with esLint. But I believe this is only solved with javascript.

Thank you guys.

```
var Data = (typeof data.method.expiration_date !== 'undefined') ? date.formatDate(String(data.method.expiration_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') : ''
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'expiration_date' of null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you don't have `expiration_date` in `method.data` so first check if it exists then do your stuff.

```
var Data = (data.method && data.method.expiration_date) ? date.formatDate(String(data.method.expiration_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add check before accessing properties of object, here  i am using `&&` operator ( [`short circuiting method`](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb) ) to check existence of value before accessing it

```
var exp_data = data && data.methoda && data.method.expiration_date
var Data = (typeof exp_data !== undefined && typeof exp_data !== undefined ) ? date.formatDate(String(exp_data), 'DD/MM/YYYY') : ''
```

In you you need to test for any false value then you can simply use this

```
var exp_data = data && data.methoda && data.method.expiration_date
var Data = exp_data ? date.formatDate(String(exp_data), 'DD/MM/YYYY') : ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`var Data = (data.method && data.method.expiration_date) ? date.formatDate(String(data.method.expiration_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') : ''`

Checks for existence of `data.method` and before referencing `data.method.expiration_date`.