# Cannot read property "*******"' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying To create custom Validation to match password and ConfirmPassword.

But I am getting the error.

I am new to angular. Please ignore my ignorance.

Is it a good idea to create custom validation to match password and Confirm password? or is there a better way out?

Here is the code.
Please help

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-form',
  templateUrl: './sample-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-form.component.scss']
})
export class SampleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  formattedMessage: string;
  passMatch: Boolean;
  formValid: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onChanges();
  }


  sample: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    inpt: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    pass: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    cpass: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, this.passwordMatch]),
    iagree: new FormControl(null, Validators.nullValidator)
  });

  onChanges(): void {
    this.sample.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      console.log("======================================");
      console.log("PASS  : " + this.sample.controls.pass.value);
      console.log("CPASS  : " + this.sample.controls.cpass.value);
      if (this.sample.controls.pass.value == this.sample.controls.cpass.value) {
        this.passMatch = true;
        console.log("MATCHED");
      } else {
        this.passMatch = false;
        console.log("MIS-MATCHED");
      }

      this.formValid = this.sample.valid;
      console.log("PASS MATCH : " + String(this.passMatch));
      console.log("FORM VALID : " + String(this.formValid));


    });
  }

  passwordMatch(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    let pass = group.controls.pass.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.cpass.value;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }

  sumbit() {

  }

}
```

I am Getting this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pass' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pass' of undefined
    at passwordMatch (sample-form.component.ts:51)
    at forms.js:1480
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:1476)
    at FormControl.validator (forms.js:1418)
    at FormControl._runValidator (forms.js:4089)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4050)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:4656)
    at new SampleFormComponent (sample-form.component.ts:25)
    at createClass (core.js:31985)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

-Ashish

Comment: `this.sample.controls` isn't set anywhere, so it's `undefined`, and you can't access property `.pass` of `undefined`. You're setting `group.controls.pass`, but not `this.sample.controls.pass`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined)

Comment: check this https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators for building custom validators.

Comment: Hi Tim ,
I have tried "group.controls.pass". But the error is still there
```
passwordMatch(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    let pass = group.controls.pass;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.cpass;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }
```

I am getting the same error :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually solved the problem.
to use the keyword "root"

```
passwordMatch(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const pass = control.root.get('pass');
    const cpass = control.root.get('cpass');

    if (pass != null && cpass != null) {
      console.log("Pass : ", pass.value);
      console.log("cpass : ", cpass.value);
      if (pass.value != cpass.value) {
        console.log("MISMATCH");
        return { PasswordMismatch: 'Password Mismatch' }
      } else {
        console.log("MATCH");
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("MISMATCH2");
      return { PasswordMismatch: 'Password Mismatch' };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `passwordMatch` function because angular will call it in different context

try

```
    cpass: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, this.passwordMatch.bind(this)]),
```

instead of

```
    cpass: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, this.passwordMatch]),
```

**Updated answer**:

You need to do both bind the `passwordMatch` method and add `pass` and `cpass` in the separate form group with generic validator
 something like this:

```
    sample = new FormGroup({
      inpt: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      iagree: new FormControl(null, Validators.nullValidator),

      confirmPasswordForm: new FormGroup({
        pass: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        cpass: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }, {
        validator: this.passwordMatch.bind(this),
      })
    });
```

But you need create nested form in you html

Comment: In custom Validation, By default, Form Controll is passed as Paramater to the custom validation function.

If I do :
passwordMatch(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
  
    console.log("FUNC : " + group.value);
    return null;
  }
I notice thet Confirm Password value is printed.
But the challange is to get the valie of Password also.
Since the control does not have the Value of "password"

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your validator to the formControl cpass, so the formControl you will get through the arguments is only cpass. That validator needs the parent level to be able to access both controls (pass and cpass). Try this instead:

```
sample: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  inpt: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  pass: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
  cpass: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  iagree: new FormControl(null, Validators.nullValidator)
}, {validators: [this.passwordMatch]});
```

That should do the trick. The error will be in sample formgroup, not in the formControl, which in my opinion makes sense because it affects to more than one form controls.