# How to access these parameters of this object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How would I access the value of `statusCode` for example?

```
{
    res: IncomingMessage {
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: '',
    }
}
```

Comment: `myObj.res.statusCode` ?

Comment: This isn't valid JSON...

Comment: this question has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: Okay - thanks for letting me know this is not valid JSON.

Comment: @newprogrammer please update your questions with details, and that piece of code does not represent valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the initial object.

If outer brackets is valid then you can access it like property name:

```
object.res.statusCode
```

or you can do it by propertyName:

```
object['res']['statusCode']
```

If outer brackets is not valid and you wrote them just for wrapping up. Then you can access status code the same way, just without mentioning res.

Comment: I always get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined'

Comment: @newprogrammer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

Optional Chaining.

Not widely supported in older browsers:

```
data?.res?.statusCode
```

Using dot notation:

```
data.res && data.res.statusCode;
```

Using property access notation:

```
data['res'] && data['res']['statusCode']
```

Using ternary operator:

```
data['res'] ? data["res"]["statusCode"] : -1
```

Answer (score -1):

`JSONObject.res.statusCode` is a correct approach.

In case that you have something like this (Replace JSONObject with the name of your JSON) :

```
 let JSONObject = {
        res: IncomingMessage {
          statusCode: 200,
          statusMessage: ''
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't have a JSON Object... JSON is a string notation

Comment: Yes...That is what JSON means... It's still not an object. **Notation** as in text

Comment: [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a standard **TEXT-BASED** format for representing structured data **BASED ON** JavaScript object syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Answer (score -1):

Your Object structure is wrong maybe you meant this

```js
ob={ res:{ IncomingMessage :{ statusCode: 200,statusMessage: ''}}}
console.log(ob.res.IncomingMessage.statusCode)
```

Comment: why is the downvote!! can anyone explain to me what is wrong with the answer, I am all open to criticism. However downvoting without explaining why, makes no sense